# Convert azure cloud service to azure web app service

Tags: c#, azure, arm, migration, azure-service-fabric

We have existing azure cloud service project running fine. But as per I hear about azure app services will fulfill my all requirements with less cost. So we have decided to convert our azure cloud service to azure app service. But I am unable to find any great step by step guide for this.

Our Cloud service contains a web role (MVC 4 project) and multiple projects including some worker roles.

My findings :-

As per my R&D I found solutions like:-

- Service fabrics
- Web app with web Jobs
- Web App with Azure functions

Due to performance issue can happen with azure webJobs so I decided to go with azure service fabrics but It gives me option to create asp.net core project to fulfill my web role requirement but lot of conflicts and reference issues occurred while i put my mvc code into asp.net core project.

Please give me any advice what is best option to convert my existing cloud service with minimal efforts.

If anyone knows about good step by step guide then please share.  Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "Due to performance issue can happen with azure webJobs" ?

Comment: @CSharpRocks I read in article https://contos.io/moving-from-old-school-azure-cloud-services-to-v2-azure-paas-cbf1e93547e5#.rwakz5pz0

However I can try Azure app service with Web Jobs. Could you please guide me to Convert my current cloud service into Azure app service with web jobs to fulfill my web role and worker role requirements. If you know then Please share helpful links/Sample for this too

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you’d like to migrate your Cloud Services to Azure App Service with WebJobs (or Azure functions) or Service Fabric, I advise you check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm) that compares the capabilities of App Service, Cloud Services, Virtual Machines, and Service Fabric.

You said you want to save money, please keep in mind using Service Fabric not always cheaper than using Cloud Services. Please add and configure Azure features for your scenarios in [Pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) and price for services/features that you choose, and you could compare and get an economical solution.

Besides, if you decide to use Service Fabric, please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cloud-services-migration-worker-role-stateless-service) to migrate your Cloud Services to Service Fabric.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Yes I want to migrate from my existing azure cloud service to azure web app service (service fabrics/Webjobs/Azure functions - preference would be cost effective and efficient way). Can I use migartion tool to convert my cloud service to azure app service?

Comment: ``Can I use migration tool to convert my cloud service to azure app service?`` As far as I know, there are not migration tools that could help us to directly and automatically migrate a existing cloud service to Azure app service. Before you do migration, you had better to know capabilities and applicable scenarios of cloud service(web role&worker role), app service&webjobs (or functions) or Service Fabric.